# Quickly fill cells with datetime based on column name in pandas?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I need to convert my cumbersome column headers into a datetime for every cell in that column. For example, I need the datetime "2001-10-06 6:00" from the column header 20011006_6_blah_blah_blah. I have a column of other datetimes that I will eventually be using to do some calculations.

Construction of an example df:

```
date_rng0=pd.date_range(start=datetime.date(2001,10,1),end=datetime.date(2001,10,7),freq='D')
date_rng1=pd.date_range(start=datetime.date(2001,10,5),end=datetime.date(2001,10,8),freq='D')
drstr0=[str(i.year)+str(i.month)+str(i.day)+'_blah' for i in date_rng0]
drstr1=[str(i.year)+str(i.month)+str(i.day)+'_blah' for i in date_rng1]
#make zero df
arr=np.zeros((len(date_rng0),len(date_rng1))) # all ones, mask out below
df=pd.DataFrame(arr,index=drstr0,columns=drstr1)
```

First I copy all the column names into the cells, column by column. This is very slow with my data:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c]=c
```

Then I convert them to datetime using an atrocious looking lambda mess:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df.loc[:,c]=df.loc[:,c].apply(lambda x: datetime.date(int(x.split('_')[0][:4]),int(x.split('_')[0][4:6]),int(x.split('_')[0][6:])))
```

Then I make a datetime column using a similar lambda function:

```
df['date_time']=df.index
df['date_time']=df.loc[:,'date_time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.date(int(x.split('_')[0][:4]),int(x.split('_')[0][4:6]),int(x.split('_')[0][6:])))

df.head()
```

gives:

```
    2001105_blah    2001106_blah    2001107_blah    2001108_blah    date_time
2001101_blah    2001-10-05  2001-10-06  2001-10-07  2001-10-08  2001-10-01
2001102_blah    2001-10-05  2001-10-06  2001-10-07  2001-10-08  2001-10-02
2001103_blah    2001-10-05  2001-10-06  2001-10-07  2001-10-08  2001-10-03
2001104_blah    2001-10-05  2001-10-06  2001-10-07  2001-10-08  2001-10-04
2001105_blah    2001-10-05  2001-10-06  2001-10-07  2001-10-08  2001-10-05
```

Then I can do a little math:

```
ndf=df.copy()
for c in df.columns:
    ndf.loc[:,c]=df.loc[:,c]-df.loc[:,'date_time']
```

Which gives what I am ultimately after:

```
    2001105_blah    2001106_blah    2001107_blah    2001108_blah    date_time
2001101_blah    4 days  5 days  6 days  7 days  0 days
2001102_blah    3 days  4 days  5 days  6 days  0 days
2001103_blah    2 days  3 days  4 days  5 days  0 days
2001104_blah    1 days  2 days  3 days  4 days  0 days
2001105_blah    0 days  1 days  2 days  3 days  0 days
```

The problem is, this process has never completed using my 2,000 x 30,000 dataframe despite walking away for 30 min. I feel like I am doing something wrong. Any suggestions to improve the efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `str.split`, `' '.join`, and `pd.to_datetime`

```
#add new column with values as the column names joined into a string
df['temp']=(' '.join(df.columns.astype(str)))

#expand the dataframe
temp=df['temp'].str.split(expand=True)

#rename the columns with original names
temp.columns=df.columns[:-1]

#parse the index to datetime
index=pd.to_datetime(df.index.str.split('_').str[0],format='%Y%m%d').to_numpy()

#substract the index to each column
newdf=temp.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.str.split('_').str[0],format='%Y%m%d')-index)

#mask only the rows where all values are non-negative
newdf=newdf[newdf.apply(lambda x: x >= pd.Timedelta(0)).all(1)]
```

Output:

```
print(newdf)

             2001105_blah 2001106_blah 2001107_blah 2001108_blah
2001101_blah       4 days       5 days       6 days       7 days
2001102_blah       3 days       4 days       5 days       6 days
2001103_blah       2 days       3 days       4 days       5 days
2001104_blah       1 days       2 days       3 days       4 days
2001105_blah       0 days       1 days       2 days       3 days
```

Comment: Nice Answer, much faster. Thanks.